# How can I have dynamic where conditions in linq asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to create a search page for my database and want to search based on different conditions,

see the image:

[image]

means I have multiple textboxes and dropdowns in search page

for example if textbox1 is the search box for searching projects name
and textbox2 is the search box for project date
and dropdown is for searching locations

if some one wants he can put multiple conditions to search or he can only search by one condition the default it should display all records.

how can I have such a linq query

my query is currently like blow that brings all records from table Projects:

```
var query = (from c in db.Projects  orderby c.ProjectId descending select c).AsEnumerable().Skip(starting).Take(2);
```

any help will be appreciated.

my search controller function:

```
    public ActionResult get_search()
    {
        string Project_name = "";
        if(Request.Form["project_name"]!=null)
        {
             Project_name = Request.Form["project_id"];
        }
        int Pro_id = 0;
        if(Request.Form["project_id"]!=null)
        {
             Pro_id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["project_id"]);
        }
        int starting = 0;
        if (Request.Form["starting"] != null)
        {
            starting = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["starting"]);
        }
        string strpost = "&ajax=1";
        strpost += "&project_id=" + Pro_id;

        var q_total = (from c in db.Projects select c);
        var d = "where == 1";
        //var query = from c in db.Projects.Take(2).Skip(2) orderby c.ProjectId descending select c;

        var query = (from c in db.Projects  orderby c.ProjectId descending select c).AsEnumerable().Skip(starting).Take(2);
        if(Request.Form["project_name"]!=null)
        {
            query = query.Where(w => w.ProjectName.Contains(Request.Form["project_name"]));
        }
        int numrows = q_total.Count();
        //int count = data.Count;
        string links = Pagination.paginate(numrows, starting, 3, "", "page", strpost);

        ViewBag.link = links;
        ViewBag.query = query;
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You just need to add `.Where()` statements based on the parameters your passed to the controller, but you have not shown you controller or view code so hard to give you an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple way:

```
var query = from c in db.Projects where((string.IsNullOrEmpty(pname)? true : c.ProjectName.Contains(pname))) orderby c.ProjectId descending select c;
```

Comment: Put && after first condition and inside Where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(second)? true : c.ProjectName.Contains(second)) than any number of conditions you want

Answer (score 2):

You can just check for your clause and add the `Where`:

```
var query = db.Projects.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(projectName))
{
     query = query.Where(w => w.Name == projectName);
}

if (date != null)
{
   query = query.Where(w => w.Date == date);
}

return query.ToList();
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you said could you explain more because I am new to MVC and Linq

Comment: @BenafshYalda In LINQ you can chain methods. You can check MSDN for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx

Comment: I am using MVC 5 I can not return query because I than pass it to view like the following code:     ViewBag.query = query;
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return PartialView("get_search2");
            return View();

Comment: @BenafshYalda you can do your filtering before you assign query to ViewBag

Comment: You have wrote your query that returns value I am calling my query inside controller

Comment: @BenafshYalda you will call this query inside you controller. Just do `ViewBag.query = query.ToList();`

Comment: I have updated my question and added my controller function search which I post data here when I click search button

Comment: @BenafshYalda so what's the problem? The code looks valid, though you're taking 2 records first and then try to search for you name in them

Comment: When I query like this it brings only my data which have been queried first time it does not brings data after skip and Take methods.

Comment: For example if I show in my list 4 records when I search from this 4 records it brings the result but if I search another record which is in table but because of limit for pagination I did not showed it, it does not bring new records means it does not query the database

Comment: @BenafshYalda of course it will not query your database again. If you want to query it again you should do it yourself.

Comment: How do I create a function that gets different conditions for search dynamically

Comment: @BenafshYalda I've shown you how to do it. Apply these conditions before you execute the query.